# edge remote debug page isn't open

Tags: android, microsoft-edge, remote-debugging, devtools

I have an app, which is running on an emulator, and I want to debug it by using browser's devtools.
In Chrome browser it worked simply -
`chrome://inspect`
and you are navigated to devtools devices page.

I tried the same on edge browser -
`edge://inspect`
as written in this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium/remote-debugging/

but the edge browser doesn't know it. It navigated me to a bing search of this string.

What do I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I test according to the doc and it can work well. I test with Microsoft Edge stable Version 85.0.564.63, Android 10 and Edge mobile 44.11.4.4140.

I guess you're using **Edge Legacy** on your computer which will cause the issue. The doc is apply to **Edge Chromium** and the latest Edge mobile for Android is also based on chromium. So you should check the Edge version on your computer and update it to the latest Edge Chromium and try again.

Result in Edge Chromium:

[image]